# Reading an internal file as a pointer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to implement a system for a game editor wherein it will load a predefined texture in the library. The texture uses a proprietary format that the library is already capable of reading, but currently only supports doing so using a pointer address and length as input.

I've currently gotten it working by moving the texture into a temporary file, but this is a fairly unoptimized workaround. I was wondering if there was any way in particular to get the address of the internal file, either with or without the stream. Here is my current (working) code, I can provide additional information on how NodeFactory works if necessary but the main thing is that it requires an address and length to work properly.

```
var resourceName = ("BrawlLib.HardcodedFiles.metal00.tex0");
string listDefault = "";
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
{
    string file;
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream((file = Path.GetTempFileName()), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    stream.CopyTo(fstream);
    tNode = NodeFactory.FromFile(null, file) as TEX0Node;
    Texture.Attach(tNode, _palette);
}
```

Comment: Put it into a memory stream and then set position to zero.  It should be the same as reading from a file.

Comment: The current implementation requires loading from a DataSource struct declared [as it is here](https://pastebin.com/2KPPweqY). The implementation is very strongly tied to having a non-null address, which I cannot receive from a MemoryStream to my knowledge.

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to cast a memory stream to a byte array and pass reference to that array? Or would that be even less optimized than the current methodology?